Show method in laravel
I'm developing an exercise platform. First, I have a list of the different technologies on which I can create exercises. Then, when I click on one of them, I need the list of available exercises. But I can't retrieve them. What can I do?
There is my method in my Controller:
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        $technology = Technology::findOrFail($id);
        return view('home.technology.show', compact('technology'));
    }

There is my view .blade:
<div class="home-content">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    @if($technology->exercises->isEmpty())
                        <p>Aucun exercice disponible pour cette technologie.</p>
                    @else
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($technology->exercises as $exercise)
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ route('exercises.show', $exercise->id) }}">{{ $exercise->name }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>

And this is my route:
    Route::resource('/technology',TechnologyController::class);

My Technology model:
class Technology extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];

    public function exercises()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Exercise::class, 'exercise_technologies');
    }
}

I know that my database is correct and doesn't require any changes, and my relationships are good too.

Try using Technology::with('exercises')->findOrFail($id);. If it doesn't work, show us your Technology model please.

It doesn't work, so I update my post, there is now my Technology model.

In the show method, before $technology, add a dd($id); to see what the value may be. Doesn't look like the route is quite right (to me, at least) for show?

At a glance, I don't see anything wrong. Could you share the table structure for the 3 tables? You can skip the irrelevant columns

Since you're using Route::resource(), change your show method to be public function show(Technology $technology) { return view('home.technology.show', ['technology' => $technology]); }. The Routes generated from Route::resource() is /technology/{technology}, which uses Route Model Binding to query your DB for a Model. Sidenote, there is also the @forelse($technology->exercises as $exercise) ... @empty ... @endforelse syntax you can use to avoid having to manually write @if($technology->exercises->isEmpty()) ... @else @foreach(...) ... @endforeach @endif
